# jQuery Modal for Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, modal-dialog

I'm looking for a way that I can create a simple modal window (or something that has similar behavior) for only a specific part of my page.

I'm working with fullcalendar and some of my data takes a long time to load, I'm looking for a way I can disable the calendar until the loading finishes without blocking other links on the page. This way if the user wants to get away from the page they still can while the loading is progressing.

I've tried SimpleModal, Spinners and a few other plugins that I can't remember the name of, and none of them seem to have an option to only block 1 part of my page.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [BlockUI](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/)

Have a look at the [element blocking section](http://malsup.com/jquery/block/#element). I think this would be exactly what you're looking for as you can specify which elements will be blocked.

Comment: Hmm... can't argue with the ease of use.

Comment: I really like the plugin but I'm having some issues getting the disabled area to appear over the area I want. I have a feeling that it's from fullcalendar's div css adding more options than I need on the BlockUI div. Any suggestions?

Comment: Hmmm. It's been awhile since I've implemented it myself, but an option when you call blockUI is to pass it your own CSS. Maybe mess with those parameters to move it to the correct place as opposed to changing anything in your existing element as I'm sure you've got that styled exactly as you want.

Answer (score 3):

you should be able to wrap the table in a DIV and add/remove an `overlay` css class to that div to make the table appear "inactive"

css will be somthing like:

```
.overlay      
{
    position:relative;     
    height:100%;     
    width:100%;    
    background-color:#FFFFFF; //set this to whatever color u want
    filter:alpha(opacity=20); //set filter and opacity to your liking
    opacity:0.2;     
    z-index:100; 
}
```

and, of course, jquery is your friend

Comment: I liked the idea, but my calendar is actually in a table cell not a table alone. When I moved the calendar inside the cell to a div so I could wrap it, things broke. Thanks for the help though!

Comment: Do u need to overlay the entire table or just the calendar? it doesnt necessarily have to a div that the css is applied to..it could be a table cell or any element really

Comment: It's just the calendar, but I don't want to mess with the css on the cell itself because the calendar has a bunch of specific formatting. So I tried moving the calendar to a div inside the table cell and wrapping it, but it got really angry at me for some reason.

Comment: you should be able to get the css to work on that particular cell. might take some trial and error though